# Inserting row in Panda if value can't be found

Tags: python, pandas, lookup, shift

Here is my dataframe:
dataframe1:

[image]

Client C is dropping off after May so there is no row for the average to get calculated. I would like to: catch out a missing value for that ID in a month's time and then add a row with zero holding to have a row to put the average in:

dataframe2:

[image]

Group by ID and shift by one month to get an error message and if there is an error, add row.
I have tried but gouping and shifting ended up leading to just a next month way further down the line.

Comment: Can you please give example data that is expressed as a pandas dataframe and show what code you've tried. Also show an example of what you expect the data to look like

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and
do not paste images of code or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here are two ways of doing this. First, a simple way, but one that uses `O[n * m]` memory for `n` distinct dates and `m` distinct IDs, because it expands the DataFrame into a 2D array (dates x IDs). Then, a second method that is a touch more complex, but that uses just the memory needed (`O[k]` where `k` is the number of rows in the output).

**Reproducible setup**

(Note to OP: in the future, please provide one as part of the question).

```py
np.random.seed(0)
n = 10
t = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-07-01', freq='MS')
i = np.arange(len(t))
i = np.sort(np.r_[i, np.random.choice(i, n - len(i), True)])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': t[i],
    'ID': np.random.choice(list('ABC'), n),
    'Holding': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
    
})

>>> df
        Date ID  Holding
0 2021-01-01  B        6
1 2021-01-01  B        7
2 2021-02-01  C        7
3 2021-03-01  A        8
4 2021-04-01  C        1
5 2021-05-01  A        5
6 2021-05-01  A        9
7 2021-06-01  A        8
8 2021-06-01  C        9
9 2021-07-01  B        4
```

**Method 1: easy to understand, but uses more memory.**

```py
# make a tmp 2D DataFrame date x ID, make sure all months are there
z = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='ID', values='Holding', aggfunc=sum).resample('MS').sum()

# optional: append an extra month with zeros
z = z.reindex(z.index.union([z.last_valid_index() + pd.DateOffset(months=1)])).fillna(0)

# at this point:
>>> z
ID             A     B    C
Date                       
2021-01-01   0.0  13.0  0.0
2021-02-01   0.0   0.0  7.0
2021-03-01   8.0   0.0  0.0
2021-04-01   0.0   0.0  1.0
2021-05-01  14.0   0.0  0.0
2021-06-01   8.0   0.0  9.0
2021-07-01   0.0   4.0  0.0
2021-08-01   0.0   0.0  0.0
```

Average of past two months (including current):

```py
>>> z.rolling(2, min_periods=0).mean()
ID             A     B    C
Date                       
2021-01-01   0.0  13.0  0.0
2021-02-01   0.0   6.5  3.5
2021-03-01   4.0   0.0  3.5
2021-04-01   4.0   0.0  0.5
2021-05-01   7.0   0.0  0.5
2021-06-01  11.0   0.0  4.5
2021-07-01   4.0   2.0  4.5
2021-08-01   0.0   2.0  0.0
```

Putting it all back together, with the avg as a second column:

```py
out = z.stack().to_frame('Holding').assign(mo2avg=z.rolling(2, min_periods=0).mean().stack())

# optional: remove entries where both columns are 0
out = out.loc[(out != 0).any(1)]

# and now:
>>> out
               Holding  mo2avg
Date       ID                 
2021-01-01 B      13.0    13.0
2021-02-01 B       0.0     6.5
           C       7.0     3.5
2021-03-01 A       8.0     4.0
           C       0.0     3.5
2021-04-01 A       0.0     4.0
           C       1.0     0.5
2021-05-01 A      14.0     7.0
           C       0.0     0.5
2021-06-01 A       8.0    11.0
           C       9.0     4.5
2021-07-01 A       0.0     4.0
           B       4.0     2.0
           C       0.0     4.5
2021-08-01 B       0.0     2.0
```

**Method 2: lean(er) in memory (never expands to full dates x IDs)**

```py
# make a tmp DataFrame with dates grouped by month start, sum Holdings
# and add a month for each ID:
z = pd.concat([
    df,
    (df.groupby('ID')['Date'].last() + pd.DateOffset(months=1)).reset_index().assign(Holding=0),
]).set_index('Date').groupby('ID').resample('MS').sum()

>>> z
               Holding
ID Date               
A  2021-03-01        8
   2021-04-01        0
   2021-05-01       14
   2021-06-01        8
   2021-07-01        0
B  2021-01-01       13
   2021-02-01        0
   2021-03-01        0
   2021-04-01        0
   2021-05-01        0
   2021-06-01        0
   2021-07-01        4
   2021-08-01        0
C  2021-02-01        7
   2021-03-01        0
   2021-04-01        1
   2021-05-01        0
   2021-06-01        9
   2021-07-01        0
```

Notice how all "missing" months have been filled for each `ID`, but only up to one month after the last valid date for that `ID`. This is needed to compute proper rolling means.

Now, we can group by `'ID'`, but leaving the `'Date'` index, so that the `RollingGroupBy` is correct:

```py
out = z.assign(mo2avg=z.reset_index('ID').groupby('ID')['Holding'].rolling(2, min_periods=0).mean())

# optional: drop rows where both Holding and avg are 0:
out = out.loc[(out != 0).any(1)]

# swap levels and sort index to make it comparable to the result
# of method 1:
out = out.swaplevel().sort_index()

# finally:
>>> out
               Holding  mo2avg
Date       ID                 
2021-01-01 B        13    13.0
2021-02-01 B         0     6.5
           C         7     7.0
2021-03-01 A         8     8.0
           C         0     3.5
2021-04-01 A         0     4.0
           C         1     0.5
2021-05-01 A        14     7.0
           C         0     0.5
2021-06-01 A         8    11.0
           C         9     4.5
2021-07-01 A         0     4.0
           B         4     2.0
           C         0     4.5
2021-08-01 B         0     2.0
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Pierre! I very much appreciate your answer and believe it should work. Will try it out right away. Apologies for not having followed standard protocol here, this was my first ever post so wasn't fully aware. Lesson learnt. Thanks again!